# Netsuite: Prevent changes to Default Billing on Customer Record

Tags: netsuite

When an employee starts a new sales order and needs to add a new Ship To, they click the Shipping Tab, then under Ship To Select, they click the + to add that Ship To to the Customer record.

A new window pops up called "Address" with this URL: .../app/common/address/transactionaddress.nl?etype=custjob&ship=T&target=shipping:shipaddresslist&label=Ship+To+Select&target2=billingtab:billaddresslist&entity_id=3177&entity=3177

We've had too many instances of the employee accidentally clicking the "Default" checkboxes on the pop-up window. I want to remove those checkboxes entirely from this "Address" pop-up, or setup a permission so that only certain roles can save a new default billing address.

I've searched high and low for the transactionaddress pop up form, but I don't think it's customizable through the UI. :(

Answer (score 0):

There is a bit of a back door way to accomplish this.

You create a before submit user event script that re-sets the default shipping and billing to the old record default shipping and billing addresses and deploy that to everyone who shouldn't be able to change the defaults.

You can also use that to keep someone from being able to save edits to the current default addresses as well. You may want to throw an error if you detect the current default address values have been changed or you may want to copy the new address to a new addressbook record and restore the old address.

Answer (score 0):

You can also add a form level client side script to disable the checkboxes.  If you have multiple address forms, you will need to deploy the script to each of them.

Comment: This is my preference but I'm new to NS scripting. Other than the Records Browser, do you have any recommended resources for digging into this?

Comment: Go to SuiteAnswers and search for Answer Id: 10118.